# How to group by a column in pandas and apply a ifelse based on column values

Tags: python, r, pandas, if-statement, data.table

I am trying to group by a column in a pandas DataFrame and apply a ifelse function that has a test that uses column values, and returns different values for true and false depending on the test.

I have accomplished this in R with ease using the data.table package, I would basically like the same in Python using pandas.

```
library(data.table)

dat <- data.table(
  i_n = c('a', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'i'),
  m_b_r = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  o_q = c(1, 8, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1),
  a_q = c(1, 5, 15, 1, 57, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1)
)

dat <- dat[, ('p_q') := ifelse(
  test =get('m_b_r') == 1,
  yes =get('a_q'),
  no =get('o_q') - data.table::shift(get('a_q'), n = 1L, type = 'lag', fill = 0 )
), by = 'i_n']
```

Comment: Use Pandas groupby and then check Where doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html

Comment: Waht is expected output?

Comment: @ZeroStack - Thank you, but R is hard for me, so ask for expected output - numbers in new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
shifted = dat.groupby('i_n')['a_q'].shift().fillna(0)
dat['p_q'] = np.where(dat['m_b_r'] == 1, dat['a_q'], dat['o_q'] - shifted)
print (dat)
  i_n  m_b_r  o_q  a_q  p_q
0   a      0    1    1  1.0
1   b      1    8    5  5.0
2   b      0    8   15  3.0
3   d      0    1    1  1.0
4   e      0    1   57  1.0
5   f      0    1    1  1.0
6   g      0    1    5  1.0
7   h      1    2    1  1.0
8   h      0    2    1  1.0
9   i      0    1    1  1.0
```

There is possible call custom function, but faster is first solution:

```
def f(x):
    x['p_q'] = np.where(x['m_b_r'] == 1, x['a_q'], x['o_q'] - x['a_q'].shift().fillna(0))
    return x

df = dat.groupby('i_n').apply(f)
print (df)
  i_n  m_b_r  o_q  a_q  p_q
0   a      0    1    1  1.0
1   b      1    8    5  5.0
2   b      0    8   15  3.0
3   d      0    1    1  1.0
4   e      0    1   57  1.0
5   f      0    1    1  1.0
6   g      0    1    5  1.0
7   h      1    2    1  1.0
8   h      0    2    1  1.0
9   i      0    1    1  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a `tidyverse` way in python:

```py
>>> from datar.all import c, f, tibble, group_by, mutate, if_else, lag
>>> 
>>> dat = tibble(  
...     i_n = c('a', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'i'),  
...     m_b_r = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),  
...     o_q = c(1, 8, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1),  
...     a_q = c(1, 5, 15, 1, 57, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1)  
... ) 
>>> 
>>> dat >> group_by(f.i_n) >> mutate(
...     p_q=if_else(
...         f.m_b_r == 1, 
...         f.a_q, 
...         f.o_q - lag(f.a_q, default=0)
...     )
... )
       i_n   m_b_r     o_q     a_q     p_q
  <object> <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64>
0        a       0       1       1       1
1        b       1       8       5       5
2        b       0       8      15       3
3        d       0       1       1       1
4        e       0       1      57       1
5        f       0       1       1       1
6        g       0       1       5       1
7        h       1       2       1       1
8        h       0       2       1       1
9        i       0       1       1       1

[Groups: i_n (n=8)]
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.